# problems with a negative top margin of a relative positioned element (vertical alignment)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align vertically a `div` inside a container with a height defined. I'm following the guide of http://www.vertical-align.com/, but I'm facing some issues.

According to the website, if I use this css with for this code:

```
#containingBlock {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#containingBlock > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    border: 1px solid green;

}

#containingBlock > div > div {
    position: relative; 
    top: -50%;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

<div id="containingBlock">
    <div>
        <div>
        This should be placed in the middle
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dC22r/)

I should obtain a text perfectly in the middle. But this doesn't happen because the `top: -50%` doesn't work. According to [Mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) the `top` property + % value should be based on the parent's height, which has the same height of its child automatically in this case. But the "automatic wrap height" does not seem to be take into consideration. If I specify a explicit height for the parent div (I mean, the first one nested), everything seems to be ok, but I would like it to take the height of its child automatically! What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the block to be positioned is known you can affect the correct positioning with negative margin (i.e 50% of the known height).

If it is **not** known you can affect it with a CSS transform as follows

```
-webkit-transform:translate(0%, -50%);
```

This moves the object vertically half it's own height...and so on

**HTML**

```
<div class="containingBlock one">
    <div>
        This should be placed in the middle
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.containingBlock {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.containingBlock > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dC22r/3/)

Comment: This is more thank OK, but it doesn't work with legacy browsers (IE 6/7). I was using the technique I mentioned above because of that. But thank you anyway!
P.S. I actually would like to understand why the above technique is not working, instead of getting what I need :-) let's say I'm more interested in "how" instead of "goal"!

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dC22r/4/

you have to set an height to the div that has to be centered then give it `top:50%` and subtract half his height with a negative `margin`.

Comment: right, I definitely have to specify a height ("dynamic" heights are not allowed with this way). Am I right?

Comment: yes because you have to subtract half his height and if there's no specified height in pixels you wouldn't know how much to subtract :)

Comment: Let me say this off topic: I hate css vertical positioning.

Comment: this is another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dC22r/5/ but it's not pretty and it really depends on what you need. it's based on line-height